# How to restart Backbone Wizard when user click "reload" (in the browser)

Tags: backbone.js, wizard

As opposed to several questions here in S.O.,

I want that my users will go back to "home" (restart the wizard) if they click the browser's "reload" button  (or F5 / Ctrl+R)

is there a way to catch the reload,

or to reliably overload it,

or to redirect after a page was reloaded?

**EDIT & Clarification**

The problem occurs because the browser re-use the same URL with # hash sign, e.g.

```
http://me.com/#something
```

When the page is reloaded, it is reloaded with the #something. 
The visitors get an empty panel (just the wizard box, not the surrounding bg & htmls)

Comment: It should already automatically restart from the initial state if the user hits reload, unless there is specific code to keep the wizard's state. This would probably look something like #step1 or whatever in the URL. Find that code and turn it off.

Without knowing exactly what Backbone Wizard plugin you're using, I couldn't tell you exactly how to do that.

Comment: thanks @Michael Pratt, i updated the question. Also, I inherited this wizard and have no clue - Where do I see which the plugin is used?